# pushing a value of a callback in javascript

Tags: javascript, methods, callback

*Hello, I am doing this challenge and I cannot figure out how to extract the value of "each" method inside the "keys" method and put those values in the array when in the challenge its written that "each" method cannot return anything? Not to mention that I had to make another method called "eachEverything" just to complete the first objective.. is there any way how to complete the challenge?*

*Declare your function 'each' as a method on the '_' object.

'each' takes two inputs:

1. a collection (array or object) and
2. a callback function.

'each' runs the callback function once for every element
in the collection (the value, key/index, and collection).
'each' does not return anything.

// YOUR CODE HERE

```
let _ = {
  eachEverything: function(collection, callback) {
    for (let coll in collection) {
      callback(`${collection[coll]} ${coll} ${JSON.stringify(collection)}`);
    }
  },

  each: function(collection, callback) {
    for (let coll in collection) {
      callback(coll);
    }
  },

  keys: function(object) {
    this.each(object, console.log);
}
};
```

// TESTS FOR EACH

```
console.log("#### object ####");
_.each({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, console.log);
console.log("#### array ####");
_.each([1, 2, 3], console.log);
```

Should print out:

```
#### object ####
1 'a' { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
2 'b' { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
3 'c' { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
#### array ####
1 0 [ 1, 2, 3 ]
2 1 [ 1, 2, 3 ]
3 2 [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

Declare a new method 'keys' on the '_' object.

'keys' should take an object as an input and return an array
of the object's keys.

You may not use the Object.keys method.

Your function should use the 'each' method in it.
*/

// Tests

```
const testObject = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 };

const expected = _.keys(testObject);
const actual = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

console.log("##### these are the tests for 'keys' #####");
if (JSON.stringify(expected) === JSON.stringify(actual)) {
  console.log('Yay!');
} else {
  console.log('Try again!');
}
```

Comment: "*'each' runs the callback function once for every element in the collection (the value, key/index, and collection).*" yet you only pass it the key in the callback. You also need to pass the value and the collection.

Comment: I know, thats why I have 2 methods, "eachEverything" is for the first objective, "each" is for the second objective. I, personally think that there is something wrong and it cannot be completed, thats why im asking here

Comment: I didn't say it cannot be completed. I pointed out that your code doesn't adhere to the instructions given.

Comment: Ok, lets say that "eachEverything" callback code now is inside of the "each", how can i complete the second objective?

Comment: I didn't say "eachEverything" should be anywhere. Because it still doesn't pass *three* arguments to the callback - it passes *one*. Pay close attention to the wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct implementation for the `each` method is to loop over the property names of the object received as an argument and then pass the following three things to the callback function:

- value of the property
- property name itself
- collection

```
each: function (collection, callback) {
    let ownPropertyNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(collection);

    // remove the "length" property in case of an array
    if (collection instanceof Array) {
      ownPropertyNames.splice(-1);
    }

    for (let key of ownPropertyNames) {
      callback(collection[key], key, collection);
    }
}
```

and for `keys` method, you can pass a callback function to `each` method that just pushes the `key`, received as an argument to an array declared inside the `keys` method.

```
keys: function(obj) {
    let keys = [];
    this.each(obj, (value, key) => keys.push(key));
    return keys;
}
```

**Working Demo:**

```js
let _ = {
  each: function (collection, callback) {
    let ownPropertyNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(collection);

    // remove the "length" property in case of an array
    if (collection instanceof Array) {
      ownPropertyNames.splice(-1);
    }

    for (let key of ownPropertyNames) {
      callback(collection[key], key, collection);
    }
  },
  keys: function(obj) {
    let keys = [];
    this.each(obj, (value, key) => keys.push(key));
    return keys;
  }
};

console.log("==================================");
console.log("TESTS FOR 'each()' method");
console.log("==================================");
console.log("#### object ####");
_.each({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, console.log);
console.log("#### array ####");
_.each([1, 2, 3], console.log);


console.log("==================================");
console.log("TESTS FOR 'keys()' method");
console.log("==================================");
const testObject = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 };

const expected = _.keys(testObject);
const actual = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

if (JSON.stringify(expected) === JSON.stringify(actual)) {
  console.log('Yay!');
} else {
  console.log('Try again!');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, any idea why there is a fourth output of "3 length [ 1, 2, 3 ]" when looping through the array?

Comment: For arrays, `getOwnPropertyNames()` returns an array containing a `length` property. Updated code snippet shows how to resolve this problem.